Imu Gazebo Plugin Problem
I know the question I'm asking may be very easy, but since I'm new to ROS2, I'd appreciate it if you could help me.
I use the Imu plugin in my project, but I don't have the ability to change its frame_id.
How can I do this? (In older versions of Gazebo there was a tag for this, but now there is no such feature or I am not familiar with it.)
I use the below Code in my urdf file.
<gazebo reference="imu_link">
<sensor name="br_imu" type="imu">
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>100</update_rate>
    <imu>
      <angular_velocity>
        <x>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
          </noise>
        </x>
        <y>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
          </noise>
        </y>
        <z>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
          </noise>
        </z>
      </angular_velocity>
      <linear_acceleration>
        <x>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
          </noise>
        </x>
        <y>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
          </noise>
        </y>
        <z>
          <noise type="gaussian">
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
          </noise>
        </z>
      </linear_acceleration>
    </imu>
    <plugin name="bytes_imu" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so">
        <ros>
            <namespace>imu</namespace>
            <remapping>~/out:=data</remapping>
        </ros>
        <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
    </plugin>
</sensor>

